# distinct select from 2 databases

Tags: mysql

I have 2 databases with the same structure massfacturation and massfacturation_old and I want to simply combine 2 queries to extract a count like:

```
> select count(distinct(sciper)) as usercount, date_format(`date`, "%Y") as year from massfacturation_old.jobs group by year;
+-----------+------+
| usercount | year |
+-----------+------+
|       160 | 2017 |
|       262 | 2018 |
|       165 | 2019 |
+-----------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and on the new one

```
> select count(distinct(sciper)) as usercount, date_format(`date`, "%Y") as year from massfacturation.jobs group by year;
+-----------+------+
| usercount | year |
+-----------+------+
|       170 | 2019 |
+-----------+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

The idea is to end up with one result for 2017, 2018, 2019, combining both results.

**Solution**

Ended up with:

```
> select count(distinct(sciper)), year FROM (SELECT sciper, date_format(`date`, "%Y") as year FROM massfacturation.jobs UNION SELECT sciper, date_format(`date`, "%Y") as year FROM massfacturation_old.jobs) AS j GROUP BY year;
+-------------------------+------+
| count(distinct(sciper)) | year |
+-------------------------+------+
|                     160 | 2017 |
|                     262 | 2018 |
|                     188 | 2019 |
+-------------------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried using UNION?

Comment: I tried with UNION SELECT, but I'm ending with a table with 2x2019, it's not combining the count

Comment: You should put the "Solution" part in an answer, not here.

Answer (score 2):

Use sub-query, consider the two outputs are `temp1` and `temp2`:

```sql
SELECT
    sum( usercount ),
    `year` 
FROM
    ( SELECT * FROM  temp1  UNION ALL SELECT * FROM  temp2  ) AS temp1 
GROUP BY
    `year`
```

**Edit**   As @ypercubeᵀᴹ mentioned in the comment, `UNION ALL` will avoid removing the duplicated rows from `temp1` and `temp2`.

---

Also if your tb and tb_old use the same `sciper` for the same user,
you may need to UNION before GROUP BY

```sql
SELECT
    `year`,
    count( sciper ) AS usercount
FROM
    ( SELECT sciper, YEAR ( `date` ) AS `year` FROM massfacturation_old 
        UNION 
        SELECT sciper, YEAR ( `date` ) AS `year` FROM massfacturation ) AS temp1 
GROUP BY
    `year`
```

In the above query, for every year and sciper combination, the `temp1` will only have one row.

Comment: Needs `UNION ALL`.

Comment: worked great with union, and same result with union all. Thanks !

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ the original query in question is using distinct, why would you use `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Because if you have a count of 100 for 2019 from one table and another 100 from the the second table, your query will remove the duplicate and show 100 as a result. I would expect the right answer to be 200 in that case.

Comment: the old table can contains "scipers" numbers also found in the 2nd table.

Comment: Add identical rows for 2020 in both table and you will see why you need UNION ALL

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ thanks, edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Side note, distinct is not a function. Something like:

```
SELECT sum(sciper), year
FROM ( 
    SELECT count(distinct sciper) as sciper, date_format(`date`, "%Y") as year 
    FROM massfacturation.jobs
    GROUP BY date_format(`date`, "%Y")
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(distinct sciper) as sciper, date_format(`date`, "%Y") as year 
    FROM massfacturation_old.jobs
    GROUP BY date_format(`date`, "%Y")
) AS T
GROUP BY year
```

Should do

Comment: I don't need to sum the "sciper" column but count all different "numbers" I can find in there. It's working with distinct and count.

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot the count function